# Is there any scripting documentation for the new MRTK v2?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, documentation, mrtk

I'm using Unity 2018.3 and am building an application in which I'm trying to do something very simple: turn off the pointer, after some command.

I can't find any scripting documentation in the GitHub repository and am wondering if it exist somewhere. What I'm finding is how to use the Unity Inspector to configure anything, half of it not working yet (e.g. controller model), but after anything is configured, can't find anything on how to use scripting to control it. Where do I look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API documentation for MRTK is available at https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/api/Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.html